# Normal distribution theoretical moments

Tags: statistics, economics

how we can show that the following equality holds

$E[(x-\mu)/\sigma]=0$

$E[(x-\mu)^2/\sigma^2-1]=0$

$E[(x-\mu)^3/\sigma^3]=0$

$E[(x-\mu)^4/\sigma^4-3]=0$

Comment: Convert each of those into someting about an integral.  Then examine the integrals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ then $Z=\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, and so you're asked to show
$$
E[Z], \quad E[Z^2]-1,\quad E[Z^3],\quad E[Z^4]-3
$$
are all equal to $0$. This can be done by calculating the approriate integrals using [the law of the unconscious statistician](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician). You can compare your expressions with this [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moments)

---

We know that $Z$ has density $f_Z$ given by
$$
f_Z(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}z^2\right),\quad z\in\mathbb{R},
$$
and consequently
$$
\begin{align}
E[Z]&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty z\cdot f_Z(z)\,\mathrm dz=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty z\cdot \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}z^2\right)\,\mathrm dz.
\end{align}
$$
Now an anti-derivative of $z\cdot \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}z^2\right)$ is the function $$
g(z):=-\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}z^2\right),\quad z\in\mathbb{R}.
$$
Thus
$$
E[Z]=\frac{1}{2\pi}\left[\lim_{z\to\infty}g(z)-\lim_{z\to -\infty}g(z)\right]=\frac{1}{2\pi}\left[0-0\right]=0.
$$

Comment: colud you please show it for the first moment $E[Z]$

Comment: @user45689: See the edit.

Comment: thanks I calculted it already. but I'm stuck at the second one $E[Z^2]$ any hint

Comment: @user45689: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/92650/25632) is a detailed explanation. But if you already know that the variance $\mathrm{Var}(Z)$ is $1$, then you can use the formula $\mathrm{Var}(Z)=E[Z^2]-E[Z]^2$.

Comment: i'm afraid i'm stuck !! how can we use the formula $Var(Z)=E[Z^2]-E[Z]^2$

Comment: If you know that $\mathrm{Var}(Z)=1$ and that $E[Z]=0$, then you can calculate $E[Z^2]$.

Comment: so i have to calculate it by integral. the way $E[Z]$ is calculated

Comment: No, that's not what I'm saying. I'm saying that if you already know that $\mathrm{Var}(Z)=1$ and from earlier you know that $E[Z]=0$, then the formula $E[Z^2]=\mathrm{Var}(Z)+E[Z]^2=1+0^2=1$ yields the result.

Comment: thanks for your guidance, I have managed to calculate it by taking integral of $E[Z^2]$ . but now I'm stuck at 3rd moment can i do it in a similar fashion ?

Comment: The third moment is $0$, because you integrate $z^3\cdot f_Z(z)$ which is an odd function. For the fourth moment I would recommend to follows [Sasha's answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/92650/25632).

Comment: thank you. I have calculated the first three momnents. but 4th $E[Z^4]-3=0$ i'm not getting help me taking the deravitive of    \begin{align}
E[Z^4]&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty z^4\cdot f_Z(z)\,\mathrm dz=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty z^4\cdot \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}z^2\right)\,\mathrm dz.
\end{align}

Comment: Again, please take a look at this [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/92650/25632). I don't think it can be done any easier than this. Just do the substitution $z=\sqrt{2u}$.

Comment: thanks, but what is the intuition behind this substitution does that mean $E[Z^4]=E[(\sqrt2u)^4]$

Comment: I don't think that there is any intuition behind it. It's just an application of [integration by substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution). No it certainly doesn't mean that $E[Z^4]=E[(\sqrt{2}u)^4]$.