# What is the expectation of a random variable raised to the $n$th power?

Tags: probability, expectation

If $Y=X^n$, with $n$ and the expectation and variance of $X$ known, what is the expectation and variance of $Y$?

Comment: Knowing the expectation and variance of $X$ is not enough information to know the moments of all orders.

Comment: I have to agree with @StefanHansen. Since expectation is just the integral of the function, it does not really give us information about the integral of a function raised to the $n$th power, in general. Although, there may be a nice form in certain cases.

Comment: What if we assume X is distributed normal?

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92648/calculation-of-the-n-th-central-moment-of-the-normal-distribution-mathcaln).

Answer (score 3):

To give this an answer, as Stefan Hansen comments:

> Knowing the expectation and variance of X is not enough information to know the moments of all orders.

As an explicit example, let $X$ be normally distributed with mean zero and variance 1, and let $W$ be +1 or -1 with probability 1/2 (the Rademacher distribution).  Then $EX = EW = 0$ and $E X^2 = E W^2 = 1$, but $E X^4 = 3$ while $E W^4 = 1$.

In the special case of the normal distribution, the distribution of a normal random variable are completely determined by its mean and variance, hence so are its higher moments.  You can find various formulas for those moments [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moments).

Answer (score -5):

Here's a partial answer: If $X$ is a Bernoulli variable, and $n\gt0$, then $E[X^n]=E[X]$ and $Var(X^n)=Var(X)$.