# How to calculate the value of $E[X^4], E[X^6],E[X^8] $....?

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, stochastic-calculus

I learned that when X is a normal random variable , $X$~ $N(0,1)$ ,

$E[X^2]=1$

$E[X^4]=1.3=3$

$E[X^6]=1.3.5=15$

$E[X^8]=1.3.5.7=105$

For the general case , when variance is s , how do you do for $E[X^4], E[X^6],E[X^8] $....?

I know that $E[X^2]=Var(X)-(E[X])^2$ = s .

I got stuck for higher degree. Please help.

Comment: It is not that simple. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92648/calculation-of-the-n-th-central-moment-of-the-normal-distribution-mathcaln) for a complete treatment

Comment: If you change only the variance but keep the mean at $0$ then multiply your $E(X^{2k})$ by $v^k$ where $v$ is the variance.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1945448/321264

Answer (score 2):

Let $X$ have mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Then $X=\sigma Z+\mu$ where $Z$ is standard normal.

Thus $X^n=(\sigma Z+\mu)^n$. Expand using the Binomial Theorem, and use the linearity of expectation and your knowledge about the $E(Z^k)$.