# Expected value of a non-standard normally distributed variable to a power

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

If calculating $\mathbb E(X^r)$ where $X \sim \mathcal N(x,y) $ where $x\neq 0$ and $y\neq 1$ (so not the standard normal distribution), and $r$ is an arbitrary constant, how would one go about doing that?

I'm having trouble finding a satisfying answer on the internet. Thanks!

Comment: Why isn´t it the standard normal distribution ? Isn´t $X\sim\mathcal N(0,1)$ ?

Comment: @callculus No, it's $N(x,y)$ for $x \neq 0, y \neq 1$.

Comment: @Ian thanks for clearing that up. My syntax here isn't the best

Comment: @ian Ah ok, != means $\neq $

Comment: @Anthony You are asking for $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi y}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty z^r e^{-(z-x)^2/2y} dz$. Change variables to $w=z-x$ to get $\int_{-\infty}^\infty (w+x)^r e^{-w^2/2y} dw$. Expand the power (using the fractional binomial theorem if need be) and then another change of variable will give you the answer as a sum of Gamma functions. They will all be $\Gamma(k+1/2)$ for an integer $k$ if $r$ itself is a nonnegative integer. (The whole thing unsurprisingly blows up if $r$ is a negative integer.)

Comment: Note that you can use scaling to reduce to the case where the variance is $1$.   But if $r$ is not an integer, how are you going to handle negative values of $X$?

Comment: I don't understand the notation $X \sim \mathcal N(x,y)$

Comment: @wolfies It means $X$ is normally distributed with mean $x$ and either variance or standard deviation $y$. Usually it's variance but it depends.

Comment: @Ian How can a random variable $X$ have as its mean the realisation of itself $X=x$? The notation is appallingly awful.

Comment: @wolfies By not using the notation $X=x$ (or $X \leq x$ etc.) anywhere. It can work fine even if it is a bit inconvenient.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Methods for Finding Raw Moments of the Normal Distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1945448/methods-for-finding-raw-moments-of-the-normal-distribution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine the result shown in my answer here:
[Expectation of a Standard Normal Random Variable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1669735/expectation-of-a-standard-normal-random-variable/1669837#1669837), with the fact that a general normal random variable with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ can be expressed as a location-scale transformation of a standard normal distribution; i.e., $$\operatorname{E}[X^r] = \operatorname{E}[(\sigma Z + \mu)^r] = \sum_{k=0}^r \binom{r}{k} \sigma^k \operatorname{E}[Z^k] \mu^{r-k}.$$