# $E[x_i^2 x_j^2]$ for white Gaussian noise

Tags: random-variables, signal-processing

If $x_n$ is a discrete time random signal and is white Gaussian noise (ergodic and WSS) so

$$E[x_n x_{n+l}]=\sigma ^2 \delta (l)$$

and

$$E[x_n]=0$$

Where $n \in \mathbb{R}$ and $l\in\mathbb{R}$

then what is:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}\sum_{j=0}^{N-1} E[x_i^2 x_j^2]$$

The problem I'm having is that I don't know if $E[x_i^2 x_j^2]=E[x_i^2]E[j_i^2]\;\forall \;i \ne j$

Comment: The expectaton values of the summands factorize for i and j different from each other, so you are left with the expectation value of the fourth powers, this is easy to evaluate.

Comment: Actually I remembered I do know how to prove $E[x_n^4]=3\sigma ^4$. But why does the expectation value factorise for $i\ne j$?

Comment: What is $\delta(\cdot)$? The Dirac delta?

Comment: Yes it's the dirac delta function.

Comment: It factorizes because the joint probability density p(xi, xj) factorizes into a product of Gaussians for xi and xj.

Comment: Ok that should have been obvious, I think I need a coffee. Problem solved. Thanks

Comment: For reference the answer is $3\sigma^4 N +\sigma^4N(N-1)=\sigma^4N(N+2)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expectation values of the summands factorize for $i\ne j$ because the joint probability density $p(x_i, x_j)$ factorizes into a product of Gaussians for $x_i$ and $x_j$. So you are left with the expectation value of the fourth powers. -- [Count Iblis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1189618/ex-i2-x-j2-for-white-gaussian-noise#comment2422045_1189618)

I do know how to prove $E[x_n^4]=3\sigma ^4$. For reference the answer is $$3\sigma^4 N +\sigma^4N(N-1)=\sigma^4N(N+2)$$  -- [texasflood](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1189618/ex-i2-x-j2-for-white-gaussian-noise#comment2422116_1189618)

A reference for $E[x_n^4]=3\sigma ^4$: [Calculation of the n-th central moment of the normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/92648/)