# Expectation of $Y=X^{6}$ : $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$?

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, expected-value, random-functions

Using LOTUS:
$$\text{E}(Y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx \Big( x^{6} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \text{exp}(-\frac{1}{2}x^{2})  \Big)$$
I have two functions multiplied inside the integral, so use Integration by Parts:
$$\int_{a}^{b} f g' = [fg]_{a}^{b} - \int_{a}^{b} f'g$$
$$f = x^{6} \rightarrow f' = 6x^{5}$$
$$g' = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \text{exp}\Big(-\frac{1}{2} x^{2}\Big) \rightarrow g \approx \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$$
so
$$\text{E}(Y) = \Big[\frac{x^{6}}{1+e^{-x}}\Big]_{-\infty}^{\infty} - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \Big( \frac{6x^{5}}{1+e^{-x}}\Big)$$
... and I'm stuck

Comment: Instead of your initial choice of $f=x^6$, try $f=x^5$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/92648/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1669837/321264.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that if $B$ is a Brownian motion, we have $B_1 \sim \mathcal N (0,1)$. The Ito formula yields
$$B_1^6 = \int_0^1 6B_s^5 d B_s + \frac 1 2 \int_0^1 30B_s^4 d s$$
and
$$B_t^4 = \int_0^t 4B_s^3dB_s + \frac 1 2\int_0^t 12 B_s^2 d s$$
Using that $\int_0^t 4B_s^3dB_s$ is a martingale (thus has mean zero),Fubini and that $B_s$ has variance $s$ we have
$$\Bbb E[B_t^4] = \frac 1 2 \int_0^t 12 \Bbb E[B_s^2] ds = \int_0^t 6 s ds = 3t^2$$
Since $\int_0^1 6B_s^5 d B_s $ is a martingale as well we have
$$\Bbb E[Y] = \Bbb E[ B_1^6 ] = 15 \int_0^1\Bbb E[B_s^4]ds = 15\int_0^1 3s^2ds = 15$$

Comment: How does one make the mental leap from something that has no odor of time to using a stochastic process?

Comment: Maybe cause I remembered that I used this method to calculate moments of certain process in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the integrand is even in a symmetric interval, then:

\begin{equation}
E(Y)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty} x^{6}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}} \,dx 
\end{equation}

Let $s=\frac{x^{2}}{2}$, which implies that: $x=\sqrt{2s} \Leftrightarrow dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}s^{-\frac{1}{2}}\,ds$. The limits do not change. So now we have:

\begin{equation}
E(Y)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty} 8s^{3}e^{-s} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}s^{-\frac{1}{2}}\,ds=\frac{8}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty} s^{3}e^{-s} s^{-\frac{1}{2}}\,ds=\frac{8}{\sqrt{\pi}}\underbrace{\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty} s^{\frac{5}{2}}e^{-s}\,ds}_{\Gamma{\left(\frac{7}{2}\right)}}
\end{equation}

Knowing that $\Gamma\left(\frac{7}{2}\right)=\displaystyle\frac{15\sqrt{\pi}}{8}$, then we can conclude that:

\begin{equation}
E(Y)=\frac{8}{\sqrt{\pi}}\times\frac{15\sqrt{\pi}}{8}=15
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Let
\begin{equation}
I_k = \int_{\mathbb R} x^{2 k} e^{-x^2/2} dx
\end{equation}
Use $x^{2(k+1)}e^{-x^2/2} = x^{2k+1}(x e^{-x^2/2})$ and deduce a relation between $I_{k+1}$ and $I_k$.

Answer (score 0):

Deriving the pdf of $Y$ first:
$$
F_Y(y) = \int_{-y^{\frac{1}{6}}}^{y^{\frac{1}{6}}} \varphi(x)dx = \Phi(y^{\frac{1}{6}}) - \Phi(-y^{\frac{1}{6}}) \\
f_Y(y)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{2 \pi}6}y^{-\frac{5}{6}}e^{-\frac{y^{\frac{1}{3}}}{2}}, y > 0\\
E[Y] = \frac{1}{3 \sqrt{2 \pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty}y^{\frac{1}{6}}e^{-\frac{y^{\frac{1}{3}}}{2}}dy = 
$$
To substitute variables, set $t = y^{\frac{7}{6}} \Leftrightarrow dt = \frac{7}{6}y^{\frac{1}{6}}dy$
$$
\mathbf{E}Y = \frac{2}{7 \sqrt{2 \pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp\left(-\frac{t^{\frac{2}{7}}}{2}\right)dt
$$
This integrates to
$$
\mathbf{E}Y = \frac{2}{7 \sqrt{2 \pi}} \cdot \frac{105 \sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{2}}=15
$$

Comment: I'm not making the edit because I'm not entirely certain this is what you mean, but if the integrand in your last integral is $e^{-\frac{t^{2/7}}{2}}$, I think it's somewhat easier to read if the $2/7$ is written horizontally rather than vertically.  (Possibly easier still if written as $\exp\left(-\frac{t^{2/7}}{2}\right)$.)

Comment: @BrianTung thanks, this $is$ what I meant. This certainly improves readability.

Comment: I added larger parentheses as a further typography tweak: `\left(` and `\right)`.  Feel free to retain or not as you see fit.