# Result on the expectation of zero-mean Gaussian with variance $\sigma^2$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, proof-writing, random-variables, gaussian-integral

I am looking for a proof of  the following result:

> Let $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$, then $\mathbb{E}[X^n] =
>  (n-1)!\sigma^n$ for all even numbers $n$, and zero for odd numbers
>   $n$.

I was able to shown that $\mathbb{E}[X^4] = 3$ through the characteristic function, namely, taking derivative of $\dfrac{1}{i^4} \dfrac{d^4 e^{-w^2/2}}{dw^4}\lvert_{w = 0}$ but I found the derivation to be extremely cumbersome, with many iterations of the product rule.

Is there a simple proof of this result? Any reference helps!

Can this result be generalized to non-zero mean Gaussians?

Comment: Why not calculate the moments directly? Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92648/calculation-of-the-n-th-central-moment-of-the-normal-distribution-mathcaln) post answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First define a random variable $Y\sim\text{Gamma}(p)$ ($p>0$) if $Y$ has density
$$
f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(p)}y^{p-1}e^{-y}\quad (y>0).
$$
It is easy to see that $EY^d=\frac{\Gamma(p+d)}{\Gamma(p)}$ by the definition of the gamma function.

Now onto the problem. Let $X$ be a standard normal random variable. It is well known that $X^2\sim\chi^2_{(1)}$ or equivalently $X^2/2\sim\text{Gamma}(1/2)$. Write $X^2\stackrel{d}{=}2W$ where $W\sim\text{Gamma}(1/2)$. Then
$$
EX^4=E(2W)^2=2^2EW^2=2^2\frac{\Gamma(1/2+2)}{\Gamma(1/2)}=2^2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}+1\right)=1(3)=3$$
where we have used the fact that $\Gamma(p+1)=p\Gamma(p)$. We can generalize to compute all even moments of a standard normal. For $k\geq 1$
$$
EX^{2k}=E(2W)^k=2^kEW^k=2^k\frac{\Gamma(1/2+k)}{\Gamma(1/2)}=2^k\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}+1\right)\cdots
\left(\frac{1}{2}+k-1\right).
$$
But we can simplify further to get that
$$
EX^{2k}=1(3)\cdots(2k-1)=\frac{(2k)!}{2^kk!}.
$$

Comment: Hi, could you provide some intuition as to why we are starting with Gamma RV/