# R-th central moment for a normal distribution with parameters N~(μ,σ^2)

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I need to prove for a normal distribution with parameters N~(μ,σ^2) that the r-th central moments are as follows:
r>2 odd => μr = 0
r even => σ^r.(r-1)(r-3)...3.1
I started by taking the integral of (x-μ)^rf(x) between -infinity and +infinity but am having troubles with terms that won't cancel and simplification, am I on the right track here and thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculation of the n-th central moment of the normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92648/calculation-of-the-n-th-central-moment-of-the-normal-distribution-mathcaln)

Comment: I think that [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92648/calculation-of-the-n-th-central-moment-of-the-normal-distribution-mathcaln) will help you out :)